# ¿Puedo filtrar un archivo XML?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

me gustaria saber si puedo filtrar un archivo `XML`. El archivo es el siguiente:

```
<Boletin_Consolidado>
<Boletin>
  <Numero V="0122"/>
  <Tipo_Boletin V="DEPARTAMENTAL"/>
  <Departamento V="31"/>
  <Desc_Departamento V="VALLE"/>
  <Detalle_Circunscripcion>
    <lin>
      <Detalle_Pregunta>
        <lin>
          <Pregunta V="001"/>
          <Total_Sufragantes V="0"/>
          <Porc_Sufragantes V="000,00"/>
          <Abstencion V="3488628"/>
          <Porc_Abstencion V="100,00"/>
          <Votos_Validos V="0"/>
          <Porc_Votos_Validos V="000,00"/>
          <Votos_No_Marcados V="0"/>
          <Porc_Votos_No_Marcados V="000,00"/>
          <Votos_Nulos V="0"/>
          <Porc_Votos_Nulos V="000,00"/>
        </lin>
      </Detalle_Pregunta>
      <Detalle_Opcion>
        <lin>
          <Opcion V="001"/>
          <Votos V="0"/>
          <Porc V="000,00"/>
          <Pregunta V="001"/>
        </lin>
        <lin>
          <Opcion V="002"/>
          <Votos V="0"/>
          <Porc V="000,00"/>
          <Pregunta V="001"/>
        </lin>
      </Detalle_Opcion>
    </lin>
  </Detalle_Circunscripcion>
</Boletin>
</Boletin_Consolidado>
```

La lista de los Departamentos continua bajo otras etiquetas llamadas `Boletin`. Lo que quiero hacer es filtrar por el codigo del Departamento `Departamento` utilizando un `select` y que me muestre esos datos.

El archivo `XML` lo recorro en `PHP` de la siguiente forma:

```
 $NacionalXML = simplexml_load_file("./ConsultaAnticorrupcion/Archivos/XML/$Nac") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    foreach ($NacionalXML as $key => $Boletin) {
    // ========== CABECERA BOLETIN ==========
    $Numero = $Boletin->Numero["V"];
    $Tipo_Boletin = $Boletin->Tipo_Boletin["V"];
    $Fecha = $Boletin->Dia["V"] . "/" . $Boletin->Mes["V"] . "/" . $Boletin->Anio["V"];
    $Hora = $Boletin->Hora["V"] . ":" . $Boletin->Minuto["V"];
    $Mesas_Instaladas = $Boletin->Mesas_Instaladas["V"];
    $Mesas_Informadas = $Boletin->Mesas_Informadas["V"];
    $Potencial_Sufragantes = $Boletin->Potencial_Sufragantes["V"];
    $Boletin_Departamental = $Boletin->Boletin_Departamental["V"];
    $Desc_Departamento = $Boletin->Desc_Departamento["V"];
    $Porc_Mesas_Informadas = $Boletin->Porc_Mesas_Informadas["V"];
    $Departamento = $Boletin->Departamento["V"];
    $Municipio = $Boletin->Municipio["V"];
    // ========== PREGUNTAS ==========
    foreach ($Boletin->Detalle_Circunscripcion->lin->Detalle_Pregunta->lin as $Pregunta) {

        $Total_Sufragantes = $Pregunta->Total_Sufragantes["V"]++;
        $Votos_Nulos = $Pregunta->Votos_Nulos["V"]++;
        $Votos_No_Marcados = $Pregunta->Votos_No_Marcados["V"]++;
        $Votos_Validos = $Pregunta->Votos_Validos["V"]++;
        $Total_Votos = $Votos_Nulos + $Votos_No_Marcados + $Votos_Validos;
    }    
    // ========== RESPUESTAS ==========
    foreach ($Boletin->Detalle_Circunscripcion->lin->Detalle_Opcion->lin as $Respuesta) {
        $Opcion = $Respuesta->Opcion["V"];
        $Votos = $Respuesta->Votos["V"];
        $Porc = $Respuesta->Porc["V"];
        $Pregunta = $Respuesta->Pregunta["V"];
    }
    }
```

Comment: Lo  quieres parsear usando php o javascript?

Comment: En el que sea mejor y se muestren los cambios en tiempo real, que apenas yo seleccione un departamento en el `select` se muestren los datos automaticamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es bastante complicado, hay tres opciones en principio.

- Parsearlo con php y hacer un ajax cada vez que se hace una selección, se puede usar [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/es/simplexml.examples-basic.php) para esto.
- Parsearlo con Javascript como si fuera DOM. Para esto se usaría [DOMParser()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), ejemplo básico [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp). Esta forma puede ser buena pero hay que hacer queries con selectores, que se pueden volver bastante complicados.
- Trasformar el xml en JSON.

Voy a ponerte un ejemplo de esta última forma, es bastante complicada si no estas acostumbrado a manejar objetos y arrays, pero es la que a la larga, según mi opinión, permite mas flexibilidad. En principio hay que bajar una librería que haga el trabajo de transformar el xml a JSON y luego a objeto literal de javascript, porque hacer esto de cero no tiene mucho sentido, y hay varias librerías que hacen lo mismo, y por mas que una librería deje de funcionar, otra hará lo mismo, porque el resultado siempre **tiene** que ser el mismo. Yo elegí esta: https://cdn.rawgit.com/abdmob/x2js/master/xml2json.js

Con el parser lo que hay que hacer es recorrer el objeto que tenemos como resultado e ir extrayendo la información que queremos de él. Algo como esto:

```
    //vamos a la parte del objeto que nos interese
    var obj = x2js.xml_str2json(xml).Boletin_Consolidado.Boletin.Detalle_Circunscripcion.lin;

    var detalleOpcion = obj.Detalle_Opcion.lin;//<-- accedemos directamente a propiedades que no es necesario iterar.
    var detallePregunta = obj.Detalle_Pregunta.lin; 

    var info = document.getElementById("info");

    detalleOpcion.forEach(function(o,i){//<-- recorremos un array

      for(let p in o){//<-- recorremos un objeto literal
      info.innerHTML += p+": "+o[p]._V+"<br>";
      }
```

Un ejémplo funcional: https://jsfiddle.net/x1hwfvan/ Yo no sé que información específica necesitas, pero creo que con eso cubre casi todas las formas que podrás usar para extraer la información.

En cuanto al select, el select te va a dar supongo algún dato para buscar en este objeto, osea que casi toda la búsqueda, los forEach o fors van a tener que estar en el callback del evento `onchange` del select. Espero que esto te sirva a vos y a otros como punto de partida para lidiar con esto.